# Azure Durable Function - counter in orchestration

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I'm building a Durable Function based on the [monitor pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-monitor#visual-studio-sample-code). I have the code below and my question is regarding the counter variable which I used for a simple exponential retry-backoff.

```
[FunctionName("RequestOrchestrator")]
public static async Task RequestOrchestrator(
    [OrchestrationTrigger] DurableOrchestrationContext monitorContext, ILogger log)
{
    DateTime endTime = monitorContext.CurrentUtcDateTime.AddHours(1);
    int counter = 0;

    while (monitorContext.CurrentUtcDateTime < endTime)
    {
        var result = await monitorContext.CallActivityAsync<bool>("GetStatusExternal", "test");

        if (result)
        {
            // all ok
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            counter++;
            // Wait for the next checkpoint with exponential backoff
            var nextCheckpoint = monitorContext.CurrentUtcDateTime.AddSeconds(5 * counter);
            if (!monitorContext.IsReplaying)
            {
                log.LogInformation($"Next check at {nextCheckpoint}.");
            }

            await monitorContext.CreateTimer(nextCheckpoint, CancellationToken.None);
        }
    }
}
```

Is the usage of the counter ok like this or does the `counter++` need to go into

```
if (!monitorContext.IsReplaying)
  counter++;
```

for it to be [replay-safe](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-checkpointing-and-replay#orchestrator-code-constraints)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You don't need the `monitorContext.IsReplaying` check around `counter++`.
You need this check only for statements you want to be run just once like logging (as in your code), status updates to an external system, etc.

To be replay-safe, you basically just need your code to be deterministic. So any code that can't be constituted in a [Pure Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) has to be moved into their own activity functions. Everything else will do.

Like the documentation states, any code that changes over time (replay times) like time-based generators, remote data from external APIs, etc. has to be in activity functions.

Comment: thanks for the explanation! So the way I use the counter for the exponential back-off is indeed ok?!

Comment: Yes. Its correct. You might want to have an upper limit to the wait time depending on your use case.